# Pass Window Reference Using PostMessage

Tags: javascript

I want to pass the Window reference using PostMessage but getting this exception

```
Uncaught DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': An object could not be cloned.
```

below is my code:

```
var postWindow = window.document.getElementById('dummyId').contentWindow;
postWindow.postMessage(window, 'http://localhost:9090');
```

How to pass this Window reference?Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Too much stuff dangling off `window` does not fall into the [supported types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm).

Pass the data you need, not *absolutely everything*.

---

> I have main MainAPP application(running in 8080) in that i have a button,when i clicked that button its open a pop with new iframe and loading content from some other server(running in 9090).when i clicked the cancel button in popup,that popup has to be closed.so i need the window reference of parent(MainApp) in popup window.

So the page in the iframe needs to post a message to the parent window saying "Close me".

The event handler handler listening for the message then needs to remove the iframe.

Make the JavaScript belonging to the window containing the frame responsible for removing the frame.

Comment: "Pass the data you need" (I can't be more specific because you haven't explained what the issue is, you've just shown an attempt at a solution which can't work)

Comment: thanks Quentin, i want to pass the window reference to some other origin(from 8080 application to 9090 application)and need that window in 9090 application to do some operation in 8080 application.

Comment: You're going round in circles. Passing `window` (which we have established impossible) is a means to an end. What is the end goal? What do you want to do with it? I can't tell you how to perform "some operation" because I have no idea what "some operation" is.

Comment: i have main MainAPP application(running in 8080) in that i have a button,when i clicked that button its open a pop with new iframe and loading content from some other server(running in 9090).when i clicked the cancel button in popup,that popup has to be closed.so i need the window reference of parent(MainApp) in popup window.

Comment: this is a no brainer ... you know how to use postMessage ... use a cunningly crafted message in a postMessage from the iframe back to the parent document  to perform the action required ... but it has to be cunning, or it wont work

Comment: @ Quentin thanks for editing your answer..any example code for this solution(+1)

Answer (score 1):

The postMessage function exist to talk cross origin. It is a tool to be able to go around security (in a secure way) when for instance an iframe has a site of different origin.

You do not want to try to send the window object into it, even if you find a way.

The restriction exists so that any iframed site cannot access and modify content of its parent window.
Instead, you should define an API of messages that can be sent and handled by the other site. But it is up to the other site to handle them by itself. That way communication can be more restricted and secure.